# Why does LLVM bitcode have duplicate symbols for constructors?

Tags: llvm, clang++

Consider the following files

**foo.h**

```
class Foo
{
  Foo();
  Foo(int x);
  void bar();
}
```

**foo.cc**

```
# include foo.h

Foo::Foo() {}
Foo::Foo(int x) {}
void Foo::bar() {}
```

When compiling these files to LLVM bitcode `foo.bc` as follows

`clang++ -c -o foo.bc -emit-llvm foo.cc`

the resulting LLVM bitcode file, `foo.bc` contains two symbols for every constructor definition but only one symbol for the function definition. Why is this?

I have tested this on both LLVM versions 3.4 and 4.0.1, and the behaviour occurs with both versions. For reference, here is the output of

`llvm-nm foo.bc`

```
T _ZN3Foo3barEv
T _ZN3FooC1Ei
T _ZN3FooC1Ev
T _ZN3FooC2Ei
T _ZN3FooC2Ev
```

-- Edit --

Based on *milleniumbug*'s comment below, [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/Two_identical_constructors_emitted_That_s_not_a_bug?lang=en) is some additional information on complete object constructors:

Comment: Check out the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-special-ctor-dtor): the one with C1 is a "complete object constructor" and C2 is a "base object constructor". (exercise for people trying to answer this question: find out why two separate definitions are needed)

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question - and a summary here would be much better than just posting a link.